# Jquery doesnt update in forms

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made the following code to replace form fields in a page that I can't edit but only manipulate. However, the code does nothing. In chrome console when I print a variable it works fine. The code is below:

```
//GET val from drop DROP DOWN
var office_id = FieldIDs["OfficeName"];//Gets the input id
var offices;//gets the value from the drop down
$("#FIELD_"+office_id).change(function(){
    offices = $(this).val();
}).change();
//The below gets the id's of all the input fields
var address_id = FieldIDs["Address"];
var address2_id = FieldIDs["Address2"];
var city_id = FieldIDs["City"];
var state_id = FieldIDs["State"];
var zip_id = FieldIDs["Zip"];
var phone_4id = FieldIDs["Number4"];//phone
var phone_id = FieldIDs["Number1"];//fax
var pdfm4 = FieldIDs["pdfm4"];
var pdfm = FieldIDs["pdfm"];
if(offices == "SoCal Accounting"){
    $('#FIELD_'+address_id).val("7421 Orangewood Avenue");
    $('#FIELD_'+address2_id).val("");
    $('#FIELD_'+city_id).val("Garden Grove");
    $('#FIELD_'+state_id).val("CA");
    $('#FIELD_'+zip_id).val("92841");
    $('#FIELD_'+phone_4id).val("+1 714.901.5800");//phone
    $('#FIELD_'+phone_id).val("+1 714.901.5811");//fax
}
```

Comment: what's the question here?

Comment: $("#FIELD_"+office_id).change(function(){
    offices = $(this).val();
}).change(); !?!?!?

Comment: As @aldux stated what is .change() at the end.  Also not sure way are you filling all of this vars from FieldIds if you are using the just once? Where exactly are you filling array FiedIDs and way if you know their names? If it is a dynamic array of fields than you should use some kind of loop to get all field ids.

Comment: Well there are many more like this I just cut it down for ease on the eyes. I'm not really sure what the change is for, I haven't used much of Jquery, I found out about change() on this site earlier. Should I take it out?